# Instantiating Generic class using field type at runtime

Tags: c#, generics

First question here.
I am trying to instantiate a generic class using the type of a field.

```
public class ValueRange<type1>
{
    type1 min;
    type1 max;
}

void foo()
{
    int k;
    ValueRange<k.GetType()> range;  
}
```

This doesn't work. Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It takes a compile-time type, like so:

```
ValueRange<int> range;
```

It's also worth noting that you typically name your types "T"; it's just the generally-accepted standard (and hence nice to read).

Comment: This actually doesn't answer the question. See Benjamins answer, that does.

Comment: James: Well, it's up to the OP to decide what answers the question :)

Comment: "At runtime" was what gave it away for me - but I'm not yet sure if I parsed that correctly either :)

Comment: Benjamin: Yeah, but he seems to be a newbie, and it's a classic problem to make with generics, I think :) Nevertheless, let us see ... *places bets*

Answer (score 8):

The sample is confusing. I suspect you want something like

```
Type genericType = typeof(ValueRange<>).MakeGenericType(k.GetType());
Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```

Comment: Was about to post something similar!

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate the type at runtime, but you cannot declare the variable like you are doing.

```
Type genericType = typeof(ValueRange<>).MakeGenericType(k.GetType());
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```

.NET 4.0 has new rules when it comes to covariance and contravariance of generic types. That should help in being able to more strongly type your variable.

**Edit**: changed example code to use helper variable `genericType` for readability.

Answer (score 1):

To make it more clear. In the example above ValueRange is my class, not a c# one.

I wonder If there is any way to avoid declaring a type twice.

```
int k;
ValueType m;
```

In this declaration the type "int" is declared twice. But this seems to me to be redundant. If, for example, I want to change the type of k, I would have to change both declarations. I knew about "Activator.CreateInstance" but this doesn't look nice to me! Too complicated!! But if there is no better solution I'll stick to it